# Error deploying from ethereum studio to ropsten

Tags: contract-deployment, ropsten, ethereum-studio

I tried to deploy a contract to ROPSTEN from Ethereum Studio using "send contract to the Net" with the following parameter:

JSON RPC URL: https://ropsten-lb.ether.camp

It is actually an small oraclize tutorial contract (Contract DieselPrice).

My deploying address (0x101a23558277e7b8c6b9642b3a0650d03fd2bdb5) has 3 ethers on ropsten.

I get the following error:
"getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ropsten-lb.ether.camp ropsten-lb.ether.camp:443"

Has anyone experienced such error?

Could not get gas price from https://ropsten-lb.ether.camp: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND ropsten-lb.ether.camp ropsten-lb.ether.camp:443

Comment: The URL is `404` anyway.

Comment: Can somebody provide me with the correct JSON RPC URL of the ROPSTEN ethercamp node?